# How to sent invitation email using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I want to invite an user in our Active Directory/Tenant. For this using Micorosoft Graph API. Code is used as below

```
  IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithTenantId(tenantID)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .Build();

        ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

        GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

        var invitation = new Invitation
        {
            InvitedUserEmailAddress = "myemailaddress@gmail.com",
            InviteRedirectUrl = "https://myapp.com"
        };

        await graphClient.Invitations
            .Request()
            .AddAsync(invitation);
```

After this, I can see the user in Azure's Active directory portal. But don't get an invitation email.

However, when I click on **Resend Invite** from Azure Portal then the invite email is coming.

Can you please guide, why the invite email is not coming when sending invite from API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set `SendInvitationMessage` to `true` in your `Invitation` object:

```
var invitation = new Invitation
        {
            InvitedUserEmailAddress = "myemailaddress@gmail.com",
            InviteRedirectUrl = "https://myapp.com",
            SendInvitationMessage = true
        };
```

For more info you can read the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/invitation?view=graph-rest-1.0)

> sendInvitationMessage Boolean Indicates whether an email should be
>   sent to the user being invited or not. The default is false.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Small q, this may not related to this post. How can we confirm that the user has accepted the invite using graph API?

Comment: @Oxygen The beta version of the user API returns a field called externalUserState which will have a value of PendingAcceptance if the user has not redeemed the invitation yet.  

Check out this [uservoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/32669014-give-us-a-way-to-verify-that-the-invitation-has-re)

Comment: @NateJackson. Cant see this property for User. I am using Microsoft Graph SDK's 1.17.0.0 version. Code is var user = await graphClient.Users["{userPrinciplename}"].Request().GetAsync(); return Convert.ToBoolean( user.ExternalUserState); // There is no property ExternalUserState. Can you please guide?

Comment: @Oxygen  as my comment said, the BETA API has these fields.   [here are the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta)